# What is the C# equivalent of 'Public Event TestEvent()'?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, events, event-handling

What is the C# equivalent of the following line of VB.NET code?

```
Public Event TestEvent()
```

Comment: According to [this converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/), it is `public delegate void TestEventEventHandler(); public event TestEventEventHandler TestEvent;`.

Comment: Go to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.ieventbindingservice(v=vs.100).aspx#Y858) and it has four tabs ,including C# and VB.just keep flipping between them,you'll find

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write event handler in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242628/how-to-write-event-handler-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Public Event TestEvent()` creates an event without parameters in VB.Net.

Since you cannot simple use

```
public event void TestEvent;
```

in C#, you either have to create a new delegate

```
public delegate void TestEventEventHandler();
public event TestEventEventHandler TestEvent;
```

or simply use `Action`, which encapsulates a method without return value and without parameters.

```
public event Action TestEvent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public event System.EventHandler testEvent;
```

Comment: this is wrong. `System.EventHandler` needs two parameters (object, EventArgs).