# How to do something when I stop clicking button

Tags: vb.net

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Button5_clicked()
    Timer1.start()
End Sub
```

And,

```
Private Sub Timer1.tick()
    A= a+1
End Sub
```

Now how i can say program when to stop the timer when I stop pressing the button

Comment: [**`MouseDown`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown(v=vs.110).aspx) + [**`MouseUp` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: So how ? Please help i'm new to programering

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service. Please do some research on your own. Here's a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242628/how-to-write-event-handler-in-vb-net